# How to join two SQL tables using javascript and ADO in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ado, jscript, activexobject

I'm using Javascript and Internet Explorer's ActiveXObjects to connect to a SQL database. I can read out results from a single table without a problem. Unfortunately, I can't figure out the syntax to join two tables that are in the same database. Here's what I'm trying:

```
//create object
var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");

//store credentials
var connectionstring = "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source={omitted}; Initial Catalog={omitted}; User ID={omitted};Password={omitted}";

//open the db connection with credentials
conn.Open(connectionstring);

//create a new record set
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

//search the record set with SQL call
rs.Open("SELECT * FROM [order] INNER JOIN OrderItems ON (order.Id = OrderItems.Id)", conn);
```

If I delete "INNER JOIN" and everything after it, I'm fine. Note that I had to put brackets around the first table's name ("order") because I think it's a protected keyword... Anyone know the right syntax for this sort of thing in Javascript?

Comment: *"Anyone know the right syntax for this sort of thing in Javascript?"* It's nothing to do with JavaScript, it's ADO. If it's not working, you should be getting an exception with some indication of *why* it's not working. For instance, `select *` means "return all columns," and you have at least one column name conflict in those tables (they both have `Id` columns), so it could be as simple as that. Try giving the tables aliases and only requesting the columns you actually want, e.g. `select o.foo, oi.bar from [order] o inner join [OrderItems] oi on [order].[Id] = [OrderItems].[Id]`.

Comment: Thanks TJ. You're right, I was getting an error previously. I forgot to post that... It said: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'. Now, I'm trying this:
    **rs.Open("SELECT o.Id FROM [order] o INNER JOIN [OrderItems] oi ON [order].[Id] = [OrderItems].[Id]", conn);**

And getting the following:
The multi-part identifier "order.Id" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the SQL syntax you are looking for:

```
SELECT Orders.Id
FROM [Orders] 
INNER JOIN OrderItems ON [Orders].Id = OrderItems.Id
```

Note that the `(` and `)` is unnecessary.

If you want to use aliases, then you must use those aliases in the rest of the `JOIN` clause:

```
SELECT o.Id 
FROM [Orders] o
INNER JOIN OrderItems oi ON o.Id = oi.Id
```

Once you have the SQL nailed down, you should be able to pass it into the `Open` method:

```
var sql = 
    'SELECT Orders.Id ' +
    'FROM [Orders] ' +
    'INNER JOIN OrderItems ON [Orders].Id = OrderItems.Id';

rs.Open(sql, conn);
```